# Terraform data filter : get multiple values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to get subnet values from another repository. For this purpose I added data aws_subnet part. However I'm having a problem with the filtering part. At the end of the values line I need to count for each subnets. I tried to use count.index and different things. But I get this error: `The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.` So how can I use * for the filter values part. Such as: `${var.vpcname}-Public-*`

My Subnets:

```
myvpc-Private-0
myvpc-Private-1
myvpc-Private-2
myvpc-Public-0
myvpc-Public-1
myvpc-Public-2
```

My data part:

```
data "aws_subnet" "public" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"    
    values = ["${var.vpcname}-Public-"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "private" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.vpcname}-Private-"]
  }
}
```

Want to see all subnets with below output part.

```
output "private" {
  value = data.aws_subnet.private.*.id
}

output "public" {
  value = data.aws_subnet.public.*.id
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using [aws_subnets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnets), not `aws_subnet`:

```
data "aws_subnets" "public" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"    
    values = ["${var.vpcname}-Public-*"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "private" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.vpcname}-Private-*"]
  }
}
```

then

```
output "private" {
  value = data.aws_subnets.private.ids
}

output "public" {
  value = data.aws_subnets.public.ids
}
```

Comment: Oh how did I skipped those, thank  you. But I still get error from;
`Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on cluster/cluster.tf line 288, in resource "aws_alb" "alb":
 188:   subnets            = [data.aws_subnets.public.ids]
    |----------------
    | data.aws_subnets.public.ids is list of string with 2 elements
Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": element 0: string required.`

Comment: @hammer89 This is about `resource "aws_alb" "alb"`, not about your subnets issue. Thus new question should be asked containing code for `resource "aws_alb" "alb"`.

Comment: I found the last problem. I called data part with `[ ]`. I removed and get success `[data.aws_subnets.public.ids]` --> `data.aws_subnets.public.ids`. Thank you @Marcin